LFU cache in Kotlin
I've been working on the classic LFU (Least Frequently Used) cache problem lately and, as a student, I kind of struggled with the algorithms I found online. I got most of the idea behind them, but It still was a nightmare replicating them.
So, what I've tried to do, is to start coding it from scratch. Here's my result (Kotlin):
package main

// Object stored in the cache, could be anything
class Object (val key: String, val value: Int)

class LeastFrequentlyUsed (private val cacheLimit :Int) {
   // Holds objects
   private val cache = mutableListOf<Object>()
   // Keeps track of hashes -> index, used in get(key) => hash(key) => index
   private val indexLinks = mutableMapOf<Int,Int>()
   // Keeps track of calls
   private val calledObjects = mutableMapOf<Int, Int>()
   // Keeps track of the last inserted index
   private var lastInserted :Int = 0

   // Collectors and printer for the LFU cache state
   private fun collectCache() :MutableList<Pair<String,Int>> {
      var collector = mutableListOf<Pair<String,Int>>()
      cache.forEach {
         collector.add(Pair(it.key, it.value))
      }
      return collector
   }
   private fun collectCounters () :MutableList<Pair<String,Int>> {
      val collector = mutableListOf<Pair<String,Int>>()
      cache.forEach {
         collector.add(Pair(
          it.key,
            calledObjects[it.key.hashCode()]!!
         ))
      }
      return collector
   }
   private fun collectIndexLinks () :MutableList<Pair<String,Int>> {
      val collector = mutableListOf<Pair<String,Int>>()
      cache.forEach {
         collector.add(Pair(
            it.key,
            indexLinks[it.key.hashCode()]!!
         ))
      }
      return collector
   }
   fun printLfu() {
      println("Cache: ${collectCache()}")
      println("Counters: ${collectCounters()}")
      println("IndexLinks: ${collectIndexLinks()}")
      println()
   }

   // LFU setter
   fun set(key :String, value: Int) {
      val hashKey = key.hashCode()
      // If we reached the cache limit we need to take away the less used item in the cache
      if (lastInserted == cacheLimit) {
         // Lower lastInserted of 1 just to bring it back to max later
         lastInserted--
         // Brings up least used item, stored in the last index of the cache
         var lessUsedItem = cache.last()
         // Removes the least used item from cache
         cache.removeLast()
         // Clears indexLinks from the element removed from cache
         indexLinks.remove(lessUsedItem.key.hashCode())
         // Clears calledObjects from the element removed from cache
         calledObjects.remove(lessUsedItem.key.hashCode())
      }
      // Adds the new element to cache
      cache.add(Object(key,value))
      // Adds the new element to indexLinks
      indexLinks[hashKey] = lastInserted
      // Adds the new element to calledObjects
      calledObjects[hashKey] = 0
      // Turns back lastInserted to max = cache limit
      lastInserted++
   }

   // LFU getter
   fun get (key :String) :Object? {
      var hashKey = key.hashCode()

      // Verify if the key is present in the LFU
      try {
          indexLinks[hashKey]
      } catch (e :java.lang.NullPointerException) {
         return  null
      }
      // Updates the calledObjects counter
      calledObjects[hashKey] = calledObjects[hashKey]!!.plus(1)
      // Gets the current element position in the cache
      val currentItemIndex = indexLinks[hashKey]!!
      if (currentItemIndex > 0 ) {
         // Gets the previous element position in the cache, which is the current -1
         val previousItemIndex = currentItemIndex - 1
         // Gets the key of the previous item to find it in calledObjects and see its number of calls
         val previousItemKey = cache[previousItemIndex].key.hashCode()
         // Checks which is the most called: the current or the previous.
         // If is the current, swap the two
         if (calledObjects[hashKey]!! > calledObjects[previousItemKey]!!) {

            // Adjusts the position in the cache
            val temp = cache[previousItemIndex]
            cache[previousItemIndex] = cache[currentItemIndex]
            cache[currentItemIndex] = temp
            // Adjusts their indices in the indexLists map
            indexLinks[hashKey] = indexLinks[hashKey]!! - 1
            indexLinks[previousItemKey] = indexLinks[previousItemKey]!! + 1
         }
      }
      return cache[indexLinks[hashKey]!!]
   }
}

fun main () {
   val lfu = LeastFrequentlyUsed(3)
   lfu.set("Alice", 10)
   lfu.set("Bob", 20)
   lfu.set("Charlie",30)
   lfu.printLfu()
   lfu.get("Charlie")
   lfu.get("Charlie")
   lfu.set("Dean", 50)
   lfu.get("Dean")
   lfu.printLfu()
}

Would someone more experienced tell me how near to an actual solution I am? Or any hints for improvement? (PS: the code actually works)
Git gist of the code
Thanks for every suggestion!

You need to describe in more detail what the problem is. Does "the code actually works" means it works as intended? If not, what exactly is wrong? Please be more specific what you need help with. If the code works as intended and you just want some feedback how it could be improved the question would be better suited on the sister site [codereview.se].

Thanks for the answer, I was actually asking for a little code review and hints about any improvement. I did not know there was an actual code review sister site. I'll re-post there then. Thanks!

As already explained in the Code Review, this implementation doesn't do what you want. The only LFU algorithms I know of that perform read/write/delete in O(1) are based on this paper. A more descriptive explanation can be found in this blog entry for example.
The basic idea is to save your items in a regular map, but instead of assigning a counter to each item that would be increased when the item is accessed, each item is assigned a frequency bucket: Whenever the item is accessed, it moves to the next bucket.
Each bucket holds a list of all items currently in this bucket, stored in insertion order. That allows you to remove the Least Recently Used (LRU) item in case of a tie, but even more important, it allows you to easily skip all items that have the same counter to reach the next frequency bucket. If the items would be stored in a single list/map, it wouldn't be possible to achieve the same in O(1).
The frequency buckets themselves need to be stored in a linked list as well in order for the next bucket to be easily determined for an item that is being accessed.
With the changes from the Code Review in mind, this is the code I would suggest:
/**
 * Cache implementation that removes the least frequently used entry whenever inserting a new entry
 *   would exceed the [capacity].
 *
 * [get], [set] and [remove] run in constant time with a complexity of `O(1)`.
 *
 * @param capacity The maximum number of entries the cache can hold.
 * @param resetOnReplace Specifies if setting a new value for an already existing key results in the
 *   internal access counter to be reset.
 */
class LeastFrequentlyUsedCache<K, V>(
    val capacity: Int,
    val resetOnReplace: Boolean = true,
) {
    private val cache: MutableMap<K, Item<K, V>> = mutableMapOf()

    private val frequenciesHead = FrequencyBucket<K>(
        frequency = 0,
        previous = null,
        next = null,
    )

    init {
        require(capacity > 0)
    }

    /**
     * Returns the value corresponding to the given [key], or `null` if such a key is not present in the map.
     */
    operator fun get(key: K): V? {
        val item = cache[key] ?: return null

        increaseFrequency(item)

        return item.value
    }

    /**
     * Associates the specified [value] with the specified [key] in the cache.
     */
    operator fun set(
        key: K,
        value: V,
    ) {
        val item = cache[key]

        if (item == null) {
            insertNew(key, value)
        } else {
            item.value = value
            if (resetOnReplace && item.frequency !== frequenciesHead)
                moveToBucket(item, frequenciesHead)
        }
    }

    /**
     * Removes the specified key and its corresponding value from the cache.
     *
     * @return the previous value associated with the key, or `null` if the key was not present in the map.
     */
    fun remove(key: K): V? =
        cache.remove(key)?.let {
            removeFromBucket(it)
            it.value
        }

    override fun toString(): String {
        val list = mutableListOf<String>()

        var bucket: FrequencyBucket<K>? = frequenciesHead
        while (bucket != null) {
            list.addAll(bucket.keys.map { "$it=${cache[it]?.value} (${cache[it]?.frequency?.frequency})" })
            bucket = bucket.next
        }

        return list.reversed().toString()
    }

    /**
     * Assumes [key] is not in the cache and makes room for a new entry and inserts it.
     */
    private fun insertNew(
        key: K,
        value: V,
    ) {
        ensureFreeCapacity()

        val newItem = Item(
            key = key,
            value = value,
            frequency = frequenciesHead,
        )
        cache[key] = newItem
        frequenciesHead.keys.add(newItem.key)
    }

    private fun ensureFreeCapacity() {
        if (cache.size < capacity) return

        val bucket =
            checkNotNull(if (frequenciesHead.keys.isEmpty()) frequenciesHead.next else frequenciesHead) {
                "Next frequency bucket is missing."
            }
        val lfu = checkNotNull(bucket.keys.firstOrNull()) {
            "No LFU item could be found."
        }

        remove(lfu)
    }

    private fun increaseFrequency(item: Item<K, V>) {
        val currentBucket = item.frequency
        val nextFrequency = currentBucket.frequency + 1
        val candidateBucket = currentBucket.next

        val nextBucket = if (candidateBucket?.frequency == nextFrequency)
            candidateBucket
        else
            currentBucket.insertNew(nextFrequency)

        moveToBucket(item, nextBucket)
    }

    private fun moveToBucket(
        item: Item<K, V>,
        newBucket: FrequencyBucket<K>,
    ) {
        removeFromBucket(item)
        item.frequency = newBucket
        newBucket.keys.add(item.key)
    }

    private fun removeFromBucket(item: Item<K, V>) {
        val bucket = item.frequency
        bucket.keys.remove(item.key)

        if (bucket.keys.isEmpty() && bucket !== frequenciesHead)
            bucket.remove()
    }

    /**
     * Internal cache item that encapsulates the publicly exposed [value].
     *
     * @param key The key of an item. Is only used internally to find an entry by its value.
     * @param value The publicly exposed value of an item.
     * @param frequency Current [FrequencyBucket], indicating how often this item was already accessed.
     */
    private class Item<K, V>(
        val key: K,
        var value: V,
        var frequency: FrequencyBucket<K>,
    )

    private class FrequencyBucket<K>(
        val frequency: Long,
        var previous: FrequencyBucket<K>?,
        var next: FrequencyBucket<K>?,
        val keys: LinkedHashSet<K> = linkedSetOf(),
    ) {
        fun insertNew(frequency: Long): FrequencyBucket<K> {
            val bucket = FrequencyBucket(
                frequency = frequency,
                previous = this,
                next = next,
            )

            next?.previous = bucket
            next = bucket

            return bucket
        }

        fun remove() {
            val currentPrevious = checkNotNull(previous) {
                "Cannot remove bucket $this because it has no previous bucket."
            }
            val currentNext = next

            currentPrevious.next = currentNext
            currentNext?.previous = currentPrevious
            previous = null
            next = null
        }
    }
}

Notes:

I added the flag resetOnReplace to toggle between resetting/keeping the current access count when a new value is set for the same key.
Instead of storing FrequencyBucket objects in a list I decided to store a reference to the previous/next bucket as part of each object. Since no random access is needed this is a more convenient way to move between buckets.
The toString method does not output the internal map of all items, instead it iterates over the list in each bucket and retrieves then retrieves the respective data from the map. That allows the items to be ordered (descending) by their access counter. It still runs in O(n), as any toString method would that outputs all items.
For debugging purposes the frequency is output here as well, although that is an implementation detail that shouldn't be publicly exposed.

This implementation of the LFU algorithm can probably still be improved, but it should be enough to get you going.
